# PHP XML Output Concatenation

Tags: php, xml

I am using XPath to query an xml document and then copy found nodes to a separate results xml file, however the problem I am having is that the XML declaration at the top gets added each time a new node is added to the results file.

Here is my php code:

```
$allEventsForVenue = $xPath->query(
            "/Ticket/EventsPoints/Event[contains(PerformanceName,'$searchParam')]"
    );

    foreach ($allEventsForVenue as $event) {

         $dstDom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
         $dstDom->appendChild($dstDom->createElement('EventsPoints'));
         $dstDom->documentElement->appendChild($dstDom->importNode($event, true));
         //echo $dstDom->saveXml();
         $dstDom->formatOutput = true;
         $strxml .= $dstDom->saveXML();
         $handle = fopen("/var/www/html/xml/searchresults$searchID.xml", "w");
         fwrite($handle, $strxml);
         fclose($handle); 
    }
```

Invalid XML File (two xml declarations in the one file):

```
->>         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <EventsPoints>
              <Event ID="17">
                    <PerformanceName>Bressie</PerformanceName>
                    <PresaleTime/>
                    <PriceRange>17 - 17</PriceRange>
                    <VenueID ID="19"/>
                </Event>
            </EventsPoints>
->>         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <EventsPoints>
              <Event ID="180">
                    <PerformanceName>U2</PerformanceName>
                    <PriceRange>20 - 20</PriceRange>
                    <VenueID ID="198"/>
                </Event>
            </EventsPoints>
```

Comment: Repeated `fopen` and `fclose` in `foreach` loop will decrease the performance.

Comment: thanks but is there any way to only run this line : $dstDom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
 once (on the first loop)

Comment: Check my answer. I created DOMDocument only once. and repeatedly append elements in it then wrote it to a file.

Comment: XSLT may help you with these kinds of operations, though it's perhaps not as easy to read as PHP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating new `DOMDocument` instance in loop. Also you are writing in each iteration. This is making new XML document on each iteration and its get appended in your xml file. What you need to do is, **loop the XML generation part**. **Not the whole thing**.

If you loop only the `appendChild` parts, your problem will be solved.

```
$dstDom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dstDom->formatOutput = true;    

foreach ($allEventsForVenue as $event) {
     $dstDom->appendChild($dstDom->createElement('EventsPoints'));
     $dstDom->documentElement->appendChild($dstDom->importNode($event, true));
}

file_put_contents("/var/www/html/xml/searchresults$searchID.xml", $dstDom->saveXML());
```

Answer (score 1):

`DomDocument` lets you output a specific node without the xml declaration.

Just include a node in saveXML, like `saveXML($node)`, with node being an `XMLNode` type object.

With this method I think you can bypass the whole "create sub-xmldocument/import node" thing, by outputting directly the desired node in a string.

Comment: Thank you. Remember to check always PHP documentation, one may overlook that some features are really easy to find there: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
enter <?php
 // Continued from example XML above.

 /* Search for <a><b><c> */
  $result = $xml->xpath('/a/b/c');

  while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo $node->asXML();
 }
?>
```